# Elasticsearch 2.3 put mapping (Attempting to override date field type) error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I have some birth_dates that I want to store as a string. I don't plan on doing any querying or analysis on the data, I just want to store it.

The input data I have been given is in lots of different random formats and some even include strings like `(approximate)`. Elastic has determined that this should be a date field with a date format which means when elastic receives a date like `1981 (approx)` it freaks out and says the input is in an invalid format.

Instead of changing input dates I want to change the date type to string.

I have looked at the documentation and have been trying to update the mapping with the `PUT` mapping API, but elastic keeps returning a parsing error.

based on the documentation here:

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

I have tried:

```
PUT /sanctions_lists/eu_financial_sanctions/_mapping
{
    "mappings":{
        "eu_financial_sanctions":{
         "properties": {
             "birth_date": {
                 "type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed"
             }
         }
       }
    }
 }
```

but returns:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {eu_financial_sanctions={properties={birth_date={type=string, index=not_analyzed}}}}]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {eu_financial_sanctions={properties={birth_date={type=string, index=not_analyzed}}}}]"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

**Question Summary**

Is it possible to override elasticsearch's automatically determined date field, forcing string as the field type?

**NOTE**

I'm using the google chrome sense plugin to send the requests

Elastic search version is 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Just remove type reference and mapping from url, you have them inside request body. [More examples.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)

```
PUT /sanctions_lists
{
    "mappings":{
        "eu_financial_sanctions":{
         "properties": {
             "birth_date": {
                 "type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed"
             }
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive just tried `PUT /sanctions_lists/_mapping` got another error `"Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"` If I don't include '_mapping' wont it try to store it as a document?

Comment: why can't you use `PUT /sanctions_lists`? I have put link on examples in to the answer.

Comment: because your method is to add a new type. I'm wanting to update an existing field. I got `"type": "index_already_exists_exception",`

then using the linked example I tried: `PUT /sanctions_lists/_mapping/eu_financial_sanctions` and get error `"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "mapper [birth_date] of different type, current_type [date], merged_type [string]"`

Comment: It is expected. You [can not change type](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-field-in-es/5397/3) in elasticsearch once it was created. You have to use different name for your field or [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) entire index.

Comment: Looks like we cant update mapping in elasticsearch 2.3 from 
>https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html
>In general, the mapping for existing fields cannot be updated.